# How to replace the value of a LPTSTR?

Tags: c++, windows

```
    LPTSTR in;
    // ...

    std::wstring wstr(in);
    boost::replace_all(wstr, "in", ",");
    wcscpy(in, wstr.data());
```

There is any other way to replace the value of a `LPTSTR`?

In the code, `LPTSTR` is a `wchar_t*`

Comment: Are you certain you need a `LPTSTR`? If the scope of `wstr` is wide enough you can `wstr.c_str()`.

Comment: Yes i need to continue with the LPTSTR i just need to change her value at a determined point.

Comment: An `LPTSTR` is not necessarily compatible with `std::wstring`.  If you want to use wide strings, then use wide strings explicitly.  If anything, that should be `LPWSTR` if you want to stick using Windows-based names.

Comment: `LPTSTR` is not allocated in your code. If it's allocated, use `wcscpy(in, wstr.c_str());` for copying. Presumably you are passing this to an API. Depending on usage, `in = wstr.data();` can be valid.

Comment: *Yes i need to continue with the LPTSTR i just need to change her value at a determined point.* -- I'll bet that this isn't the case at all.  You may think you need to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, and only if, the replacement string is smaller/equal in length to the search string, then you can modify the contents of the input string directly.

However, if the replacement string is larger in length than the search string, then you will have to allocate a new string of larger size and copy the characters you want into it as needed.

Try something like this:

```cpp
LPTSTR in = ...;

...

const int in_len = _tcslen(in);
LPTSTR in_end = in + in_len;

LPCTSTR search = ...; // _T("in")
const int search_len = _tcslen(search);

LPCTSTR replace = ...; // _T(",")
const int replace_len = _tcslen(replace);

LPTSTR p_in = _tcsstr(in, search);

if (replace_len < search_len)
{
    if (p_in != NULL)
    {
        const int diff = search_len - replace_len;

        do
        {
            memcpy(p_in, replace, replace_len * sizeof(TCHAR));
            p_in += replace_len;
            LPTSTR remaining = p_in + diff;
            memmove(found, remaining, (in_end - remaining) * sizeof(TCHAR));
            in_end -= diff;
        }
        while ((p_in = _tcsstr(p_in, search)) != NULL);

        *in_end = _T('\0');
    }
}
else if (replace_len == search_len)
{
    while (p_in != NULL)
    {
        memcpy(p_in, replace, replace_len * sizeof(TCHAR));
        p_in = _tcsstr(p_in + replace_len, search);
    }
}
else
{
    int numFound = 0;
    while (p_in != NULL)
    {
        ++numFound;
        p_in = _tcsstr(p_in + search_len, search);
    }

    if (numFound > 0)
    {
        const out_len = in_len - (numFound * search_len) + (numFound * replace_len);
        LPTSTR out = new TCHAR[out_len + 1];
        // or whatever the caller used to allocate 'in', since
        // the caller will need to free the new string later...

        LPTSTR p_out = out, found;

        p_in = in;
        while ((found = _tcsstr(p_in, search)) != NULL)
        {
            if (found != p_in)
            {
                int tmp_len = found - p_in;
                memcpy(p_out, p_in, tmp_len * sizeof(TCHAR));
                p_out += tmp_len;
            }

            memcpy(p_out, replace, replace_len * sizeof(TCHAR));
            p_out += replace_len;

            p_in = found + search_len;
        }

        if (p_in < in_end)
        {
            int tmp_len = in_end - p_in;
            memcpy(p_out, p_in, tmp_len * sizeof(TCHAR));
            p_out += tmp_len;
        }

        *p_out = _T('\0');

        delete[] in;
        // or whatever the caller uses to free 'in'...

        in = out;
    }
}
```

See why working with raw C-style string pointers is so much harder than using C++-style string classes?

Answer (score 1):

An `LPTSTR` is just a `wchar_t *`. In this case, you're trying to replace something in the data it points at.

To do that, you need to assure it points at modifiable data. In the common case of initializing it with a literal, that won't work:

```cpp
LPCTSTR foo = "Foo";
LPTSTR mFoo = (LPTSTR)"Foo";

*foo = 'a'; // won't compile
*mFoo = 'a'; // crash and burn
```

To make it modifiable, you can (for one possibility) initialize it to point at the beginning of an array of the correct type instead:

```cpp
wchar_t buffer[256] = L"Foo";

LPTSTR foo = buffer;
*foo = 'a';  // no problem
```

Modifying the string literal itself will fail, but this allocates an array, and initializes *it* from the string literal, then modifies the content of that array. And modifying the array is fine.

Comment: `LPTSTR foo = "Foo";` won't compile. I think you mean `LPCTSTR` in super weird notation.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Yeah, I should probably remember to look things up when dealing with such stuff.